# Assign a field of type Date Only using powershell will always subtract one day

Tags: 2013, development, powershell

I have the following powershell script to create a copy of a item:-

```
$web = get-spweb "http:*********"
$list = $web.lists["Action"]
$list2 = $web.lists["Risk Issue"]
foreach ($i in $list.items)
{
$a = $i["ID"];
$sourceItem = $list.items.GetItemById($a)

$versions = $sourceItem.versions;

$newItem = $list2.items.Add();

$versionCount = $versions.Count;

##We need a for loop here as we must work backwards through the version collection
for ($i = $versionCount;$i -gt 0;$i--)
{
    $version = $versions[$i-1];


    $newItem["Modified"] = $version["Modified"];

    $newItem["Created"] = $version["Created"];


    $newItem["Date_x0020_Reported"] = $version["Date_x0020_Reported"];



    $newItem.Update();

}
}
```

now all the values inside the `$newItem` were copied successfully , except for a site column named "Date Reported" as shown inthe above script , which will have a value equal to the `$version["Date_x0020_Reported"]` minus  1 day. so if `$version["Date_x0020_Reported"]` is `18/11/1990` the value inside the `$newItem["Date_x0020_Reported"]` will be `17/11/1990` not sure why, although the other date-related fields such as modified & created were copied successfully . here is my site column definition:-

[image]

Comment: My gut reaction to this is that it has something to do with time zones / daylight savings time / etc.  Something where there is a time offset that was calculated differently for your old items than it is for your new items.  Try looking into the raw values of the old date fields and see if you can discover anything.  Is the old `Date Reported` field date only, like your new one, or does it include time as well?

Comment: @DylanCristy both are of type "Date Only"..

Comment: @DylanCristy can you adivce why the daylight saving can cause this problem ? now the site i am testing the script against is a Backup from our live server which i Restore inside our test server,,to test the scripts.. now i have noted something  if i create the new item inside the test server directly (not an item that is Backup/Restore from the live server) i will not get the problem, so could the reason for the problem i am facing is that the date time is set differently inside our live server compared to our test server,, and is there a place i can check the time setting for both servers?

Comment: It's not that it's necessarily DST, it's just that DST is yet another thing that can be a factor in calculating the time offset from UTC.  As far as the time settings, I would check the system time settings (time zone, etc.) for the live server, and there are also time zone settings for the web app in SharePoint (you can check through Central Admin).  Also, if you are running from a restore...is the backup from a day ago?  Is it possible that the backup being "frozen" for a day before being restored introduced the offset?

Comment: (I am not asking because I think I know a solution, these are just the kinds of questions I would be looking into if I were having this problem.)

Comment: @DylanCristy this is the first time i read that restoring a backup site collection would cause  or might cause a frozen in the time ...i have to look into this in more details mainly to check the time setting inside the 2 servers as u mentioned.. but i do not thing that restoring a backup file will froze the time in any way...

Comment: I wouldn't expect a backup/restore to do that either, but like I said, I'm just trying to think of all the possible (unexpected) ways an offset of a day might be introduced into the system.

Comment: I've already had a similar issue and it was due to a transformed date in UTC so 2 hours were substract and 2015-12-01 00:00 become 2015-11-30 22:00. Maybe you have the same issue

Comment: @user1898765 i think u are correct, but how i can fix the UTC time differences between the 2 servers? is this related to windows OS or to sharepoint settings , or both of them ?

Comment: I think you get date in utc format and you have to transform them in your correct time zone. I suppose SP works with utc date but i don't know if it's a setting or other. If you find, i'm interrested in

Answer (score -2):

Hope I understood you, you want to subtract 1 day from original list item Date and then save and you date is not getting copied as of now

Please try this

```
$newItem["Date_x0020_Reported"] = $version["Date_x0020_Reported"].AddDays(-1);
```

this will work, I have tried and it updates value to datetime column perfectly

Comment: no i do not want to substract 1 day,, as i am getting this faulty behavioure without any effort and i am asking why !!